# how to print centered number pyramid?

Tags: java

i want to print the following pattern in Java

[image: java number pattern]

so far i have the following code it prints the correct numbers but i just can't seem to get it to center correctly

```
public class JavaNumberPatternPyramid {

    public static void printSpaces(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");
    }

    public static void printPadding(int x) {
        if (x < 10) {
            System.out.print("    ");
        } else if (x > 9 && x < 99) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            printSpaces(8 - i);
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                int x = (int)Math.pow(2, j);
                printPadding(x);
                System.out.print(x);
            }
            for (int j = i - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
                int x = (int)Math.pow(2, j);
                printPadding(x);
                System.out.print(x);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

**Edit:** currently it looks like this

[image: current output]

what am i missing, how do i center it?

Comment: What does it look like from your code?

Comment: i have added my current output.

Comment: You need more spaces at the start of each line. About 5 times as many.

Comment: You'll have to change `printSpaces(8 - i);` to something like `printSpaces((8 - i) * 4);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printSpaces(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");
    }

    public static void printPadding(int x) {
        if (x < 10) {
            System.out.print("   ");//3 spaces
        } else if (x > 9 && x < 99) {
            System.out.print("  ");//2 spaces
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            printSpaces(32 - i*4);//here you need more spaces
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

                int x = (int)Math.pow(2, j);
                printPadding(x);
                System.out.print(x);
            }
            for (int j = i - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
                int x = (int)Math.pow(2, j);
                printPadding(x);
                System.out.print(x);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

**Output:**

```
                               1
                           1   2   1
                       1   2   4   2   1
                   1   2   4   8   4   2   1
               1   2   4   8  16   8   4   2   1
           1   2   4   8  16  32  16   8   4   2   1
       1   2   4   8  16  32  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
   1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int width  = 4;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        printSpaces((8 - i) * width);
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int x = (int)Math.pow(2, j);
            printSpaces(width - ("" + x).length());
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        for (int j = i - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
            int x = (int)Math.pow(2, j);
            printSpaces(width - ("" + x).length());
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```